# Formulating an if-and-only-if statement with linear programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm trying to convert the following statement to a linear programming formulation.

> $a=b$ if and only if $c=d$

All a, b, c and d are integers in the range 1..N.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce binary variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,y_1,y_2,y_3$ and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &= 1 \tag1 \\
(1-N)x_1 + 0x_2 + 1x_3 \le a - b &\le -1x_1 + 0x_2 + (N-1)x_3 \tag2 \\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 &= 1 \tag3 \\
(1-N)y_1 + 0y_2 + 1y_3 \le c - d &\le -1y_1 + 0y_2 + (N-1)y_3 \tag4 \\
x_2 &= y_2 \tag5
\end{align}
Constraints $(1)$ and $(2)$ enforce $a=b \iff x_2 = 1$.
Constraints $(3)$ and $(4)$ enforce $c=d \iff y_2 = 1$.
Constraint $(5)$ enforces $x_2 = 1 \iff y_2 = 1$.